# matplotlib - how to restore the previous style?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Say I change the matplotlib default style by calling

```
matplotlib.style.use('classic') ### (1)
```

Then I plot something. OK... Now...

How do I restore the style which I had before?

How do I even get the name of the currently active style (before calling (1))?

Answer (score 0):

from : [matplotlib.pyplot website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rcdefaults.html)

Call `style.use('default')` to restore the default style.

To get the name of the current active plot style, [see here](https://try2explore.com/questions/12129277)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally achieved using a context manager that applies a [temporary style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-styling):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with plt.style.context('dark_background'):
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'r-o')
plt.show()
```